# Using a loop to reference and paste the value located in a Matrix/Dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, matrix, reference

Hello I am new to R was hoping to find a way to utilize a loop to identify values in a matrix or data frame based on observations in two vectors and paste the result in another vector.

Lets say you have matrix A that represents predicted male weight (lbs) based on height(column vectors) from 48"-n" and age (row vector) from 20-j.

Next you have a matrix B that has hundreds observations of men's name, height (vector h) and age (vector a).

The objective would be to output a prediction of weight for each male in a vector that we could attach to matrix B.

My R skills are limited but the code that would identify the predicted weight based on the observation for height (h) and age (a) would resemble something like this. However matrices A and B would both be imported from an excel file (not sure what effect it would have).

```
A<-rbind(c(100,105,107, .,  .,...n),

         c(105,110,112, .,  .,...n),

         c( . , . , . , . , .,...n),

         c( . , . , . , . , .,...n),

         c( .   .   .   .  . ,...n),

         c( .   .   .   .  . ,...n),

         c( j   .   .   .  . ,...n))

colnames(A)<-c(48,50,52,54,56,...n)

rownames(A)<-c(20,22,24,26,28,...n)

B<-rbind(c(Paul,48,20),

         c(Jim, 54,24),

         c(Bob, 58,28))

colnames(B)<- c(Name, h, a)

{loop code
predicted_weight <- c(A[B$h,B$a]) 

}
```

Any help would be appreciated to save me from manually identifying corresponding cells 900 times.

Comment: Thank you Rajith Thennakoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion is to use data frames over matrixes to allow for multiple data types and for the naming of rows and columns.
See the comments in the code for an explanation.

```
#Create dummy data 
#reference/lookup matrix
A<-matrix(1:25, nrow=5)
#convert to data frame for easier handling
A<-as.data.frame(A, stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
colnames(A)<-c(48,50,52,54,56)
rownames(A)<-c(20,22,24,26,28)

#target matrix
B<-rbind(c("Paul",48,20),
         c("Jim", 54,24),
         c("Bob", 56,28))

#convert to data frame for easier handling
B<-as.data.frame(B, stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
colnames(B)<- c("Name", "h", "a")

#retrieve the row and column value
answer<-sapply(1:nrow(B), function(i){A[B[i,3],B[i,2]]})
```

> data.frame(name=B[,1],answer)
>     name answer
>   Paul     1
>   Jim     18
>   Bob     25

Comment: Thanks Dave2e. You just saved me a bunch of time!